# .NET Core 3 with MVC Razor - Change date format

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-3.1

I want like to change the date formt of the datepicker to "dd/MM/yyyy".

This my code:

**Model:**

```
[Required]                
public DateTime ForDate { get; set; }
```

**View:**

```
 <div class="form-group">
     <label asp-for="ForDate" class="control-label"></label>
     <input asp-for="ForDate" class="form-control" />         
  </div>
```

I was trying to do it with Data annotation above the Model property:

```
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]
[DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
public DateTime ForDate { get; set; }
```

I was also trying to set a culture in the startup file under the Configure() section:

```
  var cultureInfo = new CultureInfo("he-IL");
  CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = cultureInfo;
  CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = cultureInfo;
  app.UseRequestLocalization();
```

Nothing helped - the datepicker is still showing 'MM/dd/yyy'

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try config `<input>` via jquery.

```
@model DataModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";
}

<div class="text-center">

    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="ForDate" class="control-label"></label>
        <input asp-for="ForDate" id="datepicker" type="text" />
    </div>
    @section Scripts
    {
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(function () {
                $("#datepicker").datepicker({
                    dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
                });
            });
        </script>
    }

</div>
```

Test result：

[image]